# Array of pointers to a struct with pointers in that struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The part that is bothering me is the last `for` loop which I used just to test whether the data is entered correctly and that it is printed using `printf` properly. The three access methods used to print the data which I entered aren't quite clear to me.

In **access method #1** I managed to print data properly using only one arrow operator to access name. The part I can't wrap my head around is why am I able to access the data without an error? I only used index to access each `production_plant_employees` structure. I know the brackets do the dereferencing, but I still don't understand what's happening there. I tried writing that part like this : `*(production_plant_employees + i)`, but it didn't work.

**Access method #2** is fully clear to me.

Now the **access method #3**, that's the one I assumed would work, but it refuses to. When written, IDE shows no errors, but when I run the program, it stops.

I am supposed to first access data in first pointer (which is `production_plant_employees`), and then then access data in second pointer (which is pointer `basic_info` which is in struct `employee`), and then, when I've gone through the 2 pointers, access the very data I am after (name, age, etc...), right?

Also, could you please show me any other possible ways of accessing the data I'm after?

```
typedef struct basicdata{
    char name[15];
    char last_name[15];
    char gender[2];
    int age;
    char birthplace[15];
    char address[15];
} BASICDATA;

typedef struct job_info {
    int employment_year;
    char job_position[20];
    char employee_pay_grade[10];
    int employee_grade;
} JOB_INFO;

typedef struct employee{
    BASICDATA *basic_info;
    JOB_INFO *job_info;
} EMPLOYEE;


int main () {

    int i;
    int choice = 0;

    EMPLOYEE *production_plant_employees;

    printf("Enter number of employees : \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    production_plant_employees = (EMPLOYEE*)calloc(choice, sizeof(EMPLOYEE));
    if (production_plant_employees == NULL) {
        printf("An error occured during memory allocation\n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < choice; ++i) {
        production_plant_employees[i].basic_info = (BASICDATA*)calloc(choice, sizeof(BASICDATA));
        if(production_plant_employees[i].basic_info == NULL) {
            printf("An error occured during memory allocation\n");
        }

        production_plant_employees[i].job_info = (JOB_INFO*)calloc(choice, sizeof(JOB_INFO));
        if(production_plant_employees[i].job_info == NULL) {
            printf("An error occured during memory allocation\n");
        }

        printf("production_plant_employees[%d].basic_info = %d\t%x\n", i, production_plant_employees[i].basic_info, production_plant_employees[i].basic_info);
        printf("production_plant_employees[%d].job_info = %d\t%x\n", i, production_plant_employees[i].job_info, production_plant_employees[i].job_info);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < choice; ++i) {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter name : \n");
        fgets(production_plant_employees[i].basic_info->name, 15, stdin);

        printf("Name of %d. employee : %s", i, production_plant_employees[i].basic_info->name) //access method#1
        printf("Name of %d. employee : %s", i, (production_plant_employees + i)->basic_info->name);  //access method #2
        printf("Name of %d. employee : %s", i, *(*(production_plant_employees +i)).basic_info->name); //access method #3 ---> why isn't this working?
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when printing pointers, use the `%p` format specifier and cast them to `void*`: `printf("production_plant_employees[%d].basic_info = %p", i, (void*)production_plant_employees[i].basic_info);` Also, `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Look up the relative precedence and associativity of the operators involved.  In particular, look at the precedence of the dereferencing operator (`*`) relative to the member-selection (`.`) and indirect member selection (`->`) operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do it is (for access method 3):

```
printf("Name of %d. employee : %s", i, (*(*(production_plant_employees +i)).basic_info).name);
```

First we start by dereferencing pointer `production_plant_employees +i`, now, we access member `basic_info` which is also a pointer & needs to get dereferenced using the second `*` to access local member `name`.

```
ptr1 = production_plant_employees +i
ptr2 = (*ptr1).basic_info
data = (*ptr2).name
```

And thus (substituting `ptr2` in `data`:

```
data = (*(*ptr1).basic_info).name
```

& finally by substituting `ptr1` :

```
data = (*(*(production_plant_employees +i)).basic_info).name
```

Comment: Oh boy... Thanks for answering so quickly, it works :D Btw. I was so close couple of minutes ago. Thanks a lot!